# React JS and Meteor JS Folder Structure

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I would like ask on how you structure your files in the folder. Can't seems to find any example when Meteor JS is combine in React JS regarding their folder structure. Thanks!

Comment: Please read this and search Google for Meteor Boilerplates. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

Comment: @gdataDan - im just confused when React JS is combined with Meteor JS,  already read the docs of Meteor

Comment: Look at this https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-webpack-es6-modules-hot-code-patching-fixes-load-order-more

Answer (score 1):

When considering structure for Meteor and React, also consider Flow Router. Structure recommendations: https://forums.meteor.com/t/folder-structure-with-react-and-flow-router/8285/1

Comment: Flow Router is not used for meteor-react for that they have react router it is preferred and also has less issues open on github compared to flow router

Answer (score 1):

Execution will be done in alphabetical order folders have high priority than files meaning folder cat will be executed before cat.js, but files in lib folder will be executed before all other folders irrespective of alphabetical order file with name 'main' will be executed in last.